# Hide Div After Click? (But what if the Div Is a banner)

Tags: javascript, html

so I have a flash games site and when users plays they will see a popup. If they click on that DIV (The popup) it will open sponsors site. And in the background I want onmouseclick to close that AD. How can I accomplish this? (The banners are not hosted by me so I have no control on it)

code:

```
<body onLoad='setTimeout("showIt()", 10000);'>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showIt() {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
    }
// 1000 = 1 sec | 60000 is 1 minute
    </script>
```

Comment: can you please write some code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot add function to div `onClick` then you can hide it after some interval with `setTimeout`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showIt() {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
      setTimeout("hideIt()", 10000);
    }
    function hideIt() {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

But if you already inserted your banner code inside your own Div, then:

```
<div id="myDiv" onClick="javascript:this.style.display='none';">
   <!-- ad banner code here -->
</div>
```